# Autofac with ASP.net v5 RC1

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

Im trying to use autofac with asp.net 5 rc1 and all of the guides Im looking at dont seem to work with rc1  here is my code

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      ...
        services.AddCaching();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSession();


        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        // Create the Autofac container builder.
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
        builder.RegisterModule(new DiRegistration());
        // Populate the services.
       //This Line fails 
        builder.Populate(services);
        // Build the container.
        var container = builder.Build();
        // Resolve and return the service provider.
        return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

when calling  builder.Populate(services); I get this error

cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'   Web.DNX 4.5.1   C:\SVN\Datayal2\Web\src\Web\Startup.cs  81

here is my project json

```
    {
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-Web-bb6d2db2-bbf8-461d-8865-db72b039dd7f",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-beta8-157",
    "Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-beta8-157",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlConfig": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Shared": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.configuration": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }

  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Please help Im sure its possibly just that some namespace changed but im undable to figure out how.

Comment: Care to post your `project.json`?

Comment: project.json posted @Dealdiane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection` to an rc1 compatible package. You can always use the latest rc1 package by using this symver `4.0.0-rc1-*` or if that doesn't work install the latest specific version (at this time of writing) that I know is compatible with rc1 (`4.0.0-rc1-177`).

You may also need to add autofac's MyGet feed url (https://www.myget.org/F/autofac/api/v3/index.json) if for some reason the Nuget feed doesn't work.

You can find all of autofac's pre-release packages from [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/gallery/autofac/).

Also, when you reference `Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection`, you don't need to explicitly reference the `Autofac` package as well because it will automatically pull it down. This saves you from specifying both versions in your project.json. In short, all you need in your `project.json` is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-rc1-177"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue it is some namespace changes looks like the autofac package is compatable with rc1 but the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection does not have an rc1 nuget package yet what I did to get it to work is I downloaded the rc1  [gitHub](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/tree/master/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection) after doing that everything worked.